# Laravel 2 tables has pivot table and 1 table has id column from the other field

Tags: laravel, relation

I have tables `USERS`, `DESIGNATIONS` and `JOBS` where in `USERS` AND `DESIGNATION` has pivot table. And `JOBS` has relation to `DESIGNATIONS` with column in the table named `designation_id`.

What I want is if the USER logged in they can only see the JOBS(has designation_id in the table) that under on his DESIGNATIONS. Please see below code. Thank you

TABLE STRUCTURE

designation_user

```
id | user_id | designation_id
```

jobs table has

```
designation_id
```

USER MODEL

```
public function designations() {
   return $this->belongsTo(Designation::class, 'designation_user');
}
```

DESIGNATION MODEL

```
public function users() {
   return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'designation_user');
}
```

Comment: Where do you use your pivot table?

Comment: I am using it to assign multiple designations to the user

Comment: I don't see your belongsToMany relationship

Comment: Yes it should be belongsTo. I already changed it